# Call Javascript Function from VBA without IE Window

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, webrequest

Using VBA, I am trying to call a Javascript function on a web page without actually having to navigate to the page in IE. The function in question adds an item to the user's shopping cart.

Here's the VBA code:

```
Dim url             As String  
Dim ReqIE           As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

url = "http://website.com/store"
Set ReqIE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

ReqIE.Open "GET", url, False
ReqIE.Send

While ReqIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
```

Note that I am retrieving the page with a web request rather than first navigating to the page in IE and then interacting with the page (this is how I see most of the web automation through VBA questions formulated).

On the retrieved page, there is a referenced JavaScript file with a number of functions in it. Here is the function I am trying to call:

```
function addToCart(pid, qty) {
    if (typeof(pid) == 'string' && pid.indexOf('product options') == 0) {
        alert('Please choose an in stock option before adding to cart.');
        return false;
    } else if (!parseInt(pid)) return false;
}
```

As such, I have tried things like:

`HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "addToCart(15622, 1)"`

This yields an "Automation error" message from the VBE. At this point, I have basically no idea what I'm doing and I'm just trying stuff I come across through my research... I think the issue is connected to the lack of an actual IE window to interact with but I could be totally wrong about that too.

Anyone know how I can move forward on this?

Comment: `debug,print HTMLBody` and see if JavaScript function is there? If not, you should simulate a browser to get that function.

Comment: Please share actual URL. I guess when you click "Add to cart" on that website,  browser sends webform XHR. You may examine the XHR in browser with developer tools, and create VBA code to add item to the cart by reproducing that XHR. So you don't need to operate with DOM and run JS.

Comment: any reason why you want to avoid a browser object?  is it just for learning ?

Comment: don't forget that the java script in a web page is meant to interact with a web browser.